# Displaying measurement of current segment in Measurement Widget of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In this ESRI measurement widget sample:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_measurement.html
when you draw a line, it dynamically displays the segment length. And, when you measure subsequent segments lengths, it add it to the previous length.

How can I add another result which dynamically shows the current segment length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [API reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/measurement-amd.html), the measurement widget does not make event listeners available for the placement of individual nodes. that being said, our new [geometryEngine](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geometryengine-amd.html#geodesiclength) can help you do calculations like this entirely on the clientside.

i was able to whip up a [simple sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/calculate-segment-length.html) in which i listen for both map 'click' and 'mouse-move' and create new polylines representing the last drawn segment dynamically and calculate its length.

Answer (score 2):

Credit should go to [@John-Gravois](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21012/john-gravois) but I needed a slightly more re-usable solution so here is the code to extend esri's measure tool and show both the length of the previous segment and the current one being drawn.

[Demo](https://davewilton.github.io/esri-measure-extended/)

[Source](https://github.com/davewilton/esri-measure-extended)

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/dom-construct",
  "dojo/number",

  "esri/dijit/Measurement",
  "esri/geometry/Polyline",
  "esri/geometry/geometryEngine"
], function (
  declare,
  lang,
  domConstruct,
  Number,
  esriMeasurement,
  Polyline,
  GeometryEngine,
  Units
) {
    return declare([esriMeasurement], {
      // description:
      //  extends esri's measure tool to add last segment and current segment properties

      //store our array of points as the user clicks
      arrMeasurePoints: [],
      //set this to false if you do not want to show the distance as the mouse moves. 
      mouseMoveMeasure: true,
      //div to display the results of the last segment measured
      resultMouseSegmentDiv: null,
      //div to display the current segment length as the mouse moves


      postCreate: function () {

        console.log('app.Measurement::postCreate', arguments);
        this.inherited(arguments);

        //hook into the map click event
        this.map.on('click', lang.hitch(this, this.calcDistance));

        //hook in to clear the points on draw end
        this.own(this.on("tool-change", lang.hitch(this, function () {
          this.arrMeasurePoints = [];
          this.resultSegmentDiv.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
          if (this.resultMouseSegmentDiv) this.resultMouseSegmentDiv.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        })));
        this.own(this.on("measure-end", lang.hitch(this, function () {
          this.arrMeasurePoints = [];
        })));

        if (this.mouseMoveMeasure) {
          this.own(this.map.on('mouse-move', lang.hitch(this, this.calcMouseDistance)));
        }

        //add a new div to contain our mouse segment length
        if (this.mouseMoveMeasure) this.resultMouseSegmentDiv = domConstruct.create('div', { 'class': 'esriMeasurementResultSegment', innerHTML: '&nbsp;' }, this.resultValueContainer.domNode);
        //add a new div to contain our segment length
        this.resultSegmentDiv = domConstruct.create('div', { 'class': 'esriMeasurementResultSegment', innerHTML: '&nbsp;' }, this.resultValueContainer.domNode);

      },

      calcDistance: function (evt) {
        try {

          //we are only going to do this for distance
          if (!this.activeTool || this.activeTool.toString().toLowerCase() !== 'distance') return false;

          this.arrMeasurePoints.push(evt.mapPoint);

          //if we have more than two create a line and measure them
          if (this.arrMeasurePoints.length < 2) return false;

          var length = this._createAndMeasureLine(this.arrMeasurePoints[this.arrMeasurePoints.length - 2], this.arrMeasurePoints[this.arrMeasurePoints.length - 1]);

          this._displaySegmentResult(length);

          return true;

        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      },

      calcMouseDistance: function (evt) {
        //if we have a point to work with we can continue
        try {

          //we are only going to do this for distance
          if (!this.activeTool || this.activeTool.toString().toLowerCase() !== 'distance') return false;

          if (this.arrMeasurePoints.length < 1) return false;

          var length = this._createAndMeasureLine(this.arrMeasurePoints[this.arrMeasurePoints.length - 1], evt.mapPoint);

          this._displayMouseSegmentResult(length);

          return true;

        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      },

      _displaySegmentResult: function (length) {
        //format the number.
        length = this._formatNumberForDisplay(length);
        this.resultSegmentDiv.innerHTML = "Last Segment lengh: " + length + " " + this.getUnit();
      },

      _displayMouseSegmentResult: function (length) {
        //format the number.
        length = this._formatNumberForDisplay(length);
        this.resultMouseSegmentDiv.innerHTML = "Segment lengh: " + length + " " + this.getUnit();
      },

      _formatNumberForDisplay: function (num) {
        return Number.format(num, { pattern: this.numberPattern + "0" });
      },

      _createAndMeasureLine: function(point1, point2) {

        var line = new Polyline(this.map.spatialReference);
        //use the last two points 
        line.addPath([point1, point2]);

        //now use the geometry engine to measure it's lengh
        //is it WGS-84 or Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere? If so use geodesic
        //geodesicLength(geometry, unit)
        var unit = this.getUnit();
        if (!unit) unit = 'kilometers';
        unit = unit.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
        var length;
        if (this.map.spatialReference.isWebMercator()) {
          length = GeometryEngine.geodesicLength(line, unit);
        } else {
          length = GeometryEngine.planarLength(line, unit);
        }

        return length;
      }


    });
  });
```